# Storing more data with stencils

Tags: texturing

How can I make a stencil control more than one textures? I got it to work with only one but each image has 4 channels for RGBA so how can I use them all separately?

Answer (score 2):

Use compositing nodes in blender to for pixel image processing.  We  used a

- [Separate RGBA Node] and selected the R .. Red Channel.

Create an image sequence if that suits you.

[image]

- In the image above we used a 3D scene with red and green object.
- In the compositing node view.  We view the red channel as intensity gray ...for red ball.  The green ball appears as black. I have clicked on a particular node to change the backgroud image of the nodes.
- In the lower left is a file input if that suits you for a image on your hard disk.  Otherwise you could map your images onto a plane.
- I did not connect the file composite output ... so I could have many images in one screen shot. Connect the image you want to the final output.
- There are many good videos on a video site such as youtube as a random example. Search Blender Compositing Nodes.  Once you see a video these nodes will seem simple.  Please excuse my noodle soup.